# WireGuard VPS dual network interface to allow all traffic to two different locations (peers)

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, vps, wireguard

I have two Raspberry Pi's in two different locations (Germany & France), which I want to use as VPN servers to access internet from different devices.

To avoid port forwarding from my local routers, I have setup a VPS (Debian) in Azure with two network interface cards and have assigned a public IP each. I am trying to setup two wireguard interfaces in the VPS so that the first interface `wg0` routes all traffic to the Raspberry Pi in Germany and the second interface `wg1` to Raspberry Pi in France.

The setup looks like this -

- (Device 1..N) -> Azure VPS (Public IP #1) (VNET: 10.2.0.4/24) -> wg0 (10.6.0.1) -> Raspberry Pi Germany (10.6.0.15) -> Internet
- (Device 1..N) -> Azure VPS (Public IP #2) (VNET: 10.4.0.4/24) -> wg1 (10.7.0.1) -> Raspberry Pi France (10.7.0.15) -> Internet

**VPS eth0**

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:45:bd:0f:03:27 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.2.0.4/24 brd 10.2.0.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6245:bdff:fe0f:327/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**VPS eth1**

```
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:45:bd:d2:5e:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.4.0.4/24 brd 10.4.0.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::6245:bdff:fed2:5e54/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Internet wasn't working in the second public ip (eth1) and I followed this guide - https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Two_Default_Gateways_on_One_System to make it work

```
cat /etc/iproute2/rt_tables

#
# reserved values
#
255     local
254     main
253     default
0       unspec
#
# local
#
#1      inr.ruhep
150 rt2
```

```
route -n

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.2.0.1        0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.2.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
10.4.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
```

```
ip rule show

0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from all to 10.4.0.4 lookup rt2
32765:  from 10.4.0.4 lookup rt2
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

```
ip route show

default via 10.2.0.1 dev eth0
10.2.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.2.0.4
10.4.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.4.0.4
```

### **Bring up wg0**

**VPS wg0 config**

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <Private Key>
Address = 10.6.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51820

### Route requests to Raspberry Pi Germany ###
PostUp = echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
PostUp = echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/proxy_arp
PostUp = ip rule add not from 10.6.0.0/24 table main # This is needed to allow SSH access after enabling connection
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

### PostDown ###
PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg0 -o wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
PostDown = ip rule del not from 10.6.0.0/24 table main
PostDown = echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/proxy_arp
PostDown = echo 0 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

### begin Raspberry Pi Germany ###
[Peer]
PublicKey = <Public Key>
PresharedKey = <Private Key>
AllowedIPs = 10.6.0.15/32, 0.0.0.0/0
### end Raspberry Pi Germany ###

...
```

```
wg-quick up wg0

[#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
[#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
[#] ip -4 address add 10.6.0.1/24 dev wg0
[#] ip link set mtu 1420 up dev wg0
[#] wg set wg0 fwmark 51820
[#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/0 dev wg0 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add not fwmark 51820 table 51820
[#] ip -4 rule add table main suppress_prefixlength 0
[#] sysctl -q net.ipv4.conf.all.src_valid_mark=1
[#] iptables-restore -n
[#] echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
[#] echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/proxy_arp
[#] ip rule add not from 10.6.0.0/24 table main
[#] iptables -A FORWARD -i wg0 -o wg0 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
[#] iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

```
ip route show

default via 10.2.0.1 dev eth0
10.2.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.2.0.4
10.4.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.4.0.4
10.6.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.6.0.1
```

```
ip rule show

0:      from all lookup local
32761:  not from 10.6.0.0/24 lookup main
32762:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
32763:  not from all fwmark 0xca6c lookup 51820
32764:  from all to 10.4.0.4 lookup rt2
32765:  from 10.4.0.4 lookup rt2
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

**Result:** All requests from  my devices are successfully routed to Raspberry Pi Germany

### **Bring up wg1**

**VPS wg1 config**

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = <Private Key>
Address = 10.7.0.1/24
ListenPort = 51821

PostUp = ip rule add not from 10.6.0.0/24 table main # This is needed to allow SSH access after enabling connection
PostUp = iptables -A FORWARD -i wg1 -o wg1 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
PostUp = iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE

PostDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth1 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = iptables -D FORWARD -i wg1 -o wg1 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
PostDown = ip rule del not from 10.6.0.0/24 table main

### begin Raspberry Pi France ###
[Peer]
PublicKey = <Public Key>
PresharedKey = <Private Key>
AllowedIPs = 10.7.0.15/32, 0.0.0.0/0
### end Raspberry Pi France ###
```

```
ip rule show
0:      from all lookup local
32758:  not from 10.6.0.0/24 lookup main
32759:  from all lookup main suppress_prefixlength 0
32760:  not from all fwmark 0xca6d lookup 51821
32761:  not from 10.6.0.0/24 lookup main
32763:  not from all fwmark 0xca6c lookup 51820
32764:  from all to 10.4.0.4 lookup rt2
32765:  from 10.4.0.4 lookup rt2
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

```
ip route show
default via 10.2.0.1 dev eth0
10.2.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.2.0.4
10.4.0.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 10.4.0.4
10.6.0.0/24 dev wg0 proto kernel scope link src 10.6.0.1
10.7.0.0/24 dev wg1 proto kernel scope link src 10.7.0.1
```

**Result:** Connecting from my devices, `wg0` does not work anymore and all requests to `wg1` are now routed to `Azure Public IP #1`

I am a new to networking and wireguard and cannot get my head around where it's going wrong. Help!

**Edit:** I found a simpler solution than using a network interface per WireGuard server. I ended up setting up multiple WireGuard servers using [docker](https://github.com/linuxserver/docker-wireguard) and mapping different VPS ports to each of the containers. I found this [link](https://jakew.me/wireguard-docker/) useful.